# Get only parent items ids of nestedsortable plugin

Tags: jquery, nested, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using nestedsortable plugin https://github.com/ilikenwf/nestedSortable
I am trying to get only the parent items id or class and append to an input text field, not as serialized data or as array just with plain data with comma separated. Here is my code

```
var ns = jQuery('.sortable').nestedSortable({
                forcePlaceholderSize: true,
                handle: 'div',
                helper: 'clone',
                items: 'li',
                opacity: .6,
                placeholder: 'placeholder',
                revert: 250,
                tabSize: 30,
                tolerance: 'pointer',
                toleranceElement: '> div',
                maxLevels: 4,
                expandOnHover: 700,
                startCollapsed: false,
                update: function(event, ui) {
                    var arr = jQuery(this).nestedSortable('toArray');
                    var i, n;
                    var attrs = [];
            for (i = 0, n = arr.length; i < n; i++) {               
                attrs.push(jQuery('#' + arr[i]).attr('class')+',');
            }
            jQuery("#sortedelements").val(attrs);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Call toArray method, loop that array and push data to string comma-separeted as you wish.

Comment: Yes, i am trying it but it is not working see my updated question. I am little lack of knowledge in javascript.